# Using reflection in a factory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection, coding-style

I have a factory which can build many types of object and it may grow.

Would it be a good idea to use reflection to return all the different types instead of calling every method in the `getPrototypes()` method?

It would look like this with reflection :

```
public final class ShapeFactory
{
    private ShapeFactory(){} // no instance

    public static Shape buildSquare()
    {
        return new Square(2);
    }

    public static Shape buildCircle()
    {
        return new Circle(2);
    }

    public static Shape buildTriangle()
    {
        return new Triangle(2, 2, 2);
    }

    // and many more shapes...

    public static List<Shape> getPrototypes()
    {
        final List<Shape> prototypes = new ArrayList<>();

        // using reflection, call every build function
        final Method[] methods = ShapeFactory.class.getMethods();
        for(final Method picked : methods)
        {
            if(picked.getReturnType() == Shape.class && picked.getParameterTypes().length == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    prototypes.add((Shape)picked.invoke(null));
                }
                catch(final Exception e)
                {
                    // this is an example, do not ignore
                    // exceptions in real code
                }
            }
        }

        return prototypes;
    }
}
```

Sorry for using the Shape example.

Edit: The shapes are cloneable prototypes.
Edit #2: Improved the example in case someone uses it.

Comment: Yes, is good practice: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37547/Exploring-Factory-Pattern

In c#

Comment: If you can afford the performance cost of reflection then yes no reason not to make life simpler. But do make sure the cost is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be a good idea to use reflection to return all the different types instead of calling every method in the getPrototypes() method?

It is a reasonable thing to do.  The reflective code is more complicated and fragile, but it means that you don't need to change `getPrototypes()` when you add a new shape builder method.  It depends on which is more important to you.

However, you should NOT squash exceptions like you are doing.  And maybe you should be more selective of the methods that you use to create prototypes.  (The current version will FAIL if you add a method that returns a `Shape` but takes arguments ... or isn't a builder.)

Comment: Yes, this was only for the example.

Comment: I put a warning in the example about ignoring exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you want type checking done at compile time, or you want the flexibility of runtime exploration at the expense of your compile time checks.

Both options are perfectly valid approaches.

Comment: In this case, I think reflection makes it cleaner and more flexible. Thanks!